# How to check amount of VRAM in Windows 98?

Tags: vmware, windows-98, vram

I'm running a Virtual Machine in VMWare Player with Windows 10 as the host and Windows 98 SE as the guest. I'm trying to give the virtual machine more VRAM and have added `svga.vramSize = "16777216"`to my VMX file to allocate more VRAM but I have notice no difference in the way it handles games such as Doom and Earthworm Jim. I was wondering if anyone knew a way to check the amount of VRAM that the machine has been given.

Thanks.

Comment: This might get better answers on [retrocomputing.se]. Compare [What constitutes “retro”?](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2/357) on [meta.retrocomputing.se].

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use dxdiags to check that, though with my particular configuration (virtualbox + scitech display doctor, it dosen't work quite right.

Fire up dxdiags from `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\dxdiag.exe` and check the *display* tab.

I'm half certain device properties would show it to you too, but I can't check that for the same reasons.
[image]

Comment: I just get n/a for approx. total memory when I run it.

Comment: hm, the fact that its a VM is doing strange things. vmware *does* have non hacky support for it so it ought to work.

Comment: I do get an error whilst it's running saying 'Problem getting extra sound info' but that can't have anything to do with the display device, can it?

Comment: It would indicate there's something odd with the drivers. The output of that tool might be useful for further troubleshooting - but I've probably forgotten more than I remember about windows 98.

Comment: I've reinstalled DirectX and now I get no errors but it's still saying N/A

Comment: ah, out of ideas there then